# What is the benefit of adding YearWeek when year and week exist as separate columns?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm looking at data model and there is column for date, year, week, yearweek.

Yearweek is concatenation of year and week.

What is the benefit of having the YearWeek column when year and week are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be used for various things. I have one in my table for sorting purposes. e.g. if you wanted to display "Week 3, 2023" in a table or chart as a label, you'd use your column as a sort by column.

It called about be used to simplify weekly time intelligence e.g. create a filter this many weeks in the past which easily crosses year boundaries etc

Comment: But I can place year and week in a table visual to get same answer

Comment: Sometimes customers want labels that are written out like "Week 3, 2023" which won't be sorted correctly unless you have a sort by column. You can check your model using something like Measure Killer to see if it is even being used and how. You could remove it but as it is a numeric column with low cardinality, it takes up almost no space.

Comment: I second what David said. Sometimes you need/want them together.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's related to performance as well. If you are adding the column in the database, you are losing performance while creating a table and gaining performance on the report population as the week-year is ready. No need to apply any concatenation on the reporting side. And this is true for the opposite way.

Now it's our decision, where we need better performance.